# Is there a way to track push notification received if user does not tap it

Tags: ios

Actually, what I want to do is track if a push notification is received on the device, even when the app is in background or not running and the user does not tap on it?

Comment: Try this with Voip

Answer (score 0):

**Unfortunately this is not possible.**

Only when user interacts with your notification in a way that triggers running the app can the app have possibility to respond to this action - by sending a ping to your analytics server for example.